# How do I check the price of the games on the Nintendo eShop?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-eshop

I currently live in New Zealand, and I want to buy a New 3DS here.

If I bought a new New Zealand (Australian) 3DS, all the games sold here have an insane mark-up compared to other countries, and I really don't want to pay the extra price.

So here's what I want to do: I want to buy games on the Nintendo eShop, be it Australian or New Zealand (if there is even one for NZ), but I can't check the price of the games on the eShop without accessing it using a 3DS. I can't use my old US 3DS, because the only countries I can change to on there are in the US region.

Is the price of the games on the Nintendo eShop the same as your retailer's? And if not, how do I check it?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will work in New Zealand or not, but here in the US you can also visit the eShop on your computer at http://www.nintendo.com/games/3ds. You can even buy the games on your computer (which gives you a code to enter on your 3DS, IIRC).

Comment: You can change your region with a link in the upper-right of the page you linked. Unfortunately, http://www.nintendo.com.au/, the Australia/New Zealand site, does not allow you to purchase games or view prices.